# react native Error: Actions must be plain objects. Instead, the actual type was: 'string'. You may need to add middleware

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

am using React redux in react native but facing this error. i have followed many solutions but no one worked for me, hers is more detail about my actions and reduces and store

---

```
action.js 
  export const AddNow =()=>{
      return "ADD_NUM"
  }

  export const DelNow =()=>{
    return "DEL_NUM"
}
```

---

```
in reducer folder -> MyBook.js

const initialState = 30;
const MyBook = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_NUM":
      return initialState +1;
    
    case "DEL_NUM":
      return initialState -1;
  } 
  return state;
};

export default MyBook
```

---

```
in redcures folder index.js 

import MyBook from "./MyBook";
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';

const rootreducers=combineReducers({ cartIMyBooktems})

export default rootreducers;
```

---

```
in store ->index.js
import {createStore,applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'; 
import rootreducers from '../reducers/index';



export default store = createStore(rootreducers, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

---

```
in my app.js

import { AddNow , DelNow} from "../../actions";
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux'
 
const dispatch = useDispatch();
  <CustomBTN 
        onPress={()=>{dispatch(AddNow) }}
        
        />
```

i created this and followed one video tutorial but its not working for me but working for him. can anyone please help me? am beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says it all.

Your dispatch action is dispatching a string

```js
  export const AddNow =()=>{
      return "ADD_NUM" //this action dispatches a string (returns a string)
  }
```

this is causing "actual type was string"

It tells you, it is expecting a plain object. A plain object with a type property is also expected in your reducers

```js
///
switch (action.type)
///
```

It is expecting a plain object with `type` property.

update your action.js to

action.js

```
  export const AddNow =()=>{
      return {
       type: "ADD_NUM"
    }

  }

  export const DelNow =()=> {
    return {
     type: "DEL_NUM"
    } 
  }
```

now both your actions are returning plain objects, with a type property, as expected by redux dispatch and your reducers

also, since AddNow and DelNow are functions, they should be camelCase.

`addNow`, `delNow`

With regards to your book state always being 31.

in your reducers, you are always using the initial value as the modified value. The reducers recieve the current state as as the first parameter `state` which is defualted to `initialState`

update your reducers to use the `state` parameter

```
const initialState = 30;
const MyBook = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_NUM":
      return state  +1; //update initialState to state 
    
    case "DEL_NUM":
      return state -1; //update initialState to state 
  } 
  return state;
};

export default MyBook
```

Comment: @Gandzai sir old, problem is solved but now facing new  its in reducer why only showing 31 even i called many time that function

Comment: `case "ADD_NUM": return initialState +1;` here you are always using the initial state to add one, which will always be 31. Change `initialState` to `state`  which will give you `case "ADD_NUM": return state +1;`. Do this for both ADD_NUM and DEL_NUM cases

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please accept it if it worked for you.